# Django /subdirectory/admin/ redirects to /admin/login/?next=/admin/

Tags: python, django, nginx

I set up a Django server on port 8011, and have a nginx serving it as a subdirectory on port 80.

Static files, good.

Pages, good.

But when I access /subdirectory/admin/, it takes me to: /admin/login/?next=/admin/

Which is of course a 404 error, but if I access /subdirectory/admin/login/?next=/admin/, it works fine.

Any ideas? Do I need to set a variable in the settings.py?

`urls.py`:

```
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /sdc {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8011/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your nginx configuration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done

Comment: Not sure if this is a good method, but I am using Django's `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` variable now to set the directory.

Comment: Yes that was going to be my suggestion.

Comment: Does this also work with serving the static files? I can get the links and admin working, but static files are not served

Comment: Got the same issue. How do you fix this in the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838911/django-throws-a-302-error-when-i-try-to-redirect-a-user-after-password-change[Check this case, this could help you][1]

Answer (score -3):

I believe what is happening is that when django sees you aren't logged in, it redirects you to the url named 'admin:login'. It figures out that url by reversing what it sees in your urls.py, which is this case comes out to be `admin/login/` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls). This means it doesn't know it is operating within `/subdirectory/`.

Try add subdirectory in urls.py

```
url(r'^subdirectory/admin/', admin.site.urls),
```