# Django throws a 302 error when I try to redirect a user after password change

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have a `view` that handles the password change for a user

```
@csrf_exempt
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_request = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        try:
            u = User.objects.get(username=user_request.get("user"))
            u.set_password(user_request.get("password"))
            u.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return HttpResponse("Failure")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

This does change the password for the user since next time if I have to login, I have to supply the new password.But it doesn't redirect the user immediately to the home page (which in turn will redirect to login page since the user is logged out).

I have a similar view for login given below

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html")
```

But it does redirect the user to the home page if the authentication is successful.

Then why doesn't any redirection happens when the user changes their password?I instead get a `302` status code.

Comment: Show the status messages.

Comment: You should append a slash at the end though(request, "login.html/")

Comment: @dEv no, absolutely not.

Comment: Are you calling the `change_password` view through an ajax call?

Comment: @thebjorn yes I am.

Comment: If you want to redirect the page it would be easier to do it the same way you do the `login_view` (it's possible to do it with ajax, but it's twice the traffic if you're going to redirect instead of changing the current page). In addition you might want to look at hooking into Django's built-in login system (e.g. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html)

Answer (score 4):

"302 Found" *is* a re-direct.  It includes a "Location" header in the HTTP response, telling the browser where to go instead.

Comment: ok I see. So if I have mentioned a `/` indicating it to go the home page, why doesnt' it work?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that.  It sounds to me like a client-side issue, but I'm not a web developer so it's beyond my ken.

Comment: I got this error: MultipleObjectsReturned at /admin
get() returned more than one User -- it returned 2!

Comment: @reza_khalafi, that's a completely unrelated question and shouldn't be asked here.  But your problem is that you have a query that's returning multiple results, but the way you use it expects only a single result.

You're probably doing `<your query>.objects.get()` instead of `<your query>.objects.all()` or something similar. Or you have an error in your database so some value that should have a unique constraint doesn't.